# Python re.sub use non-greedy mode (.*?) with end of string ($) it comes greedy!

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

Code:

```
str = '<br><br />A<br />B'
print(re.sub(r'<br.*?>\w$', '', str))
```

It is expected to return `<br><br />A`, but it returns an empty string `''`!

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please don't ever use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: Uh... hey... you're not parsing HTML with regular expressions, are you?

Comment: If you need to parse a lot of HTML then you'd be better of using something like http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ instead of regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Greediness works from left to right, but not otherwise. It basically means "don't match unless you failed to match". Here's what's going on:

1. The regex engine matches `<br` at the start of the string.
2. `.*?` is ignored for now, it is lazy.
3. Try to match `>`, and succeeds.
4. Try to match `\w` and fails. Now it's interesting - the engine starts backtracking, and sees the `.*?` rule. In this case, `.` can match the first `>`, so there's still hope for that match.
5. This keep happening until the regex reaches the slash. Then `>\w` can match, but `$` fails. Again, the engine comes back to the lazy `.*` rule, and keeps matching, until it matches`<br><br />A<br />B`

Luckily, there's an easy solution: By replacing `<br[^>]*>\w$` you don't *allow* matching outside of your tags, so it should replace the last occurrence.
Strictly speaking, this doesn't work well for HTML, because tag attributes can contain  `>` characters, but I assume it's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

The non-greediness won't start later on like that.  It matches the first `<br` and will non-greedily match the rest, which actually need to go to the end of the string because you specify the `$`.

To make it work the way you wanted, use

```
/<br[^<]*?>\w$/
```

but usually, it is not recommended to use regex to parse HTML, as some attribute's value can have `<` or `>` in it.